# Trying to use containers, ArrayList class

Tags: java

I'm trying to learn how to use java's container classes.
I found the following url on programming containers: [link](http://vapvarun.com/study/softE/john%20wiley%20and%20sons%20-%20programming%20with%20object-oriented%20programming/5399final/lib0041.html)

I cannot get their sample code to work, they have

```
class ListOps {
    public static void main( String[] args )
    {
        List animals = new ArrayList();                                     //(A)
        animals.add( "cheetah" );                                           //(B)
        animals.add( "lion" );
        animals.add( "cat" );
       ....
       ....
```

I cannot get the add to work, I get syntax error on token "cheetah" delete this token, my code:

```
public class cStringContainer {

    ArrayList animals = new ArrayList();                                     //(A)
    animals.add( "cheetah" ); // error hear, syntex error

}
```

Comment: I can't get the syntax error, just warnings due to the non-parameterized list. Are you sure you can reproduce your issue with this single snippet? Didn't you omit some other code?

Comment: @sp00m, note that there is no method so he cannot use `add()` here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What happened to main?

```
public class cStringContainer {
public static void main( String[] args ) { 
ArrayList animals = new ArrayList();                                     //(A)
animals.add( "cheetah" ); // error hear, syntex error
}
}
```

Comment: Hi,It is a android project, the main is inside the framework. I use eclipse to add a new class, and I put the sample code inside it.

Answer (score 5):

You need a method inside your class, you can't simply put code right inside a Class unless it is in a static block. Copy the main method from the example and it will work.